# Not getting any speedup from OpenMP

Tags: c++, image-processing, openmp

I'm putting together an image processing program and I'm working with relatively small images (640x480). Running in serial, it takes just under 0.1s to process an image, but I need it to be much faster as it will later be taking in video streams.

I have two or three nested for loops that I'm trying to speed-up, and am trying to use #pragma omp parallel for.

One of the for loops is structured like this:

```
//xLen = 640, yLen = 480
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int y=0;y<yLen;y++) {
    double yR = y/((double)yLen);

    double y1 = dyl*yR+yt_1;
    double y2 = dyr*yR+yt_2;

    double x1 = (y1-yt_1)/ml+xt_1;
    double x2 = (y2-yt_2)/mr+xt_2;


    for(int x=0;x<xLen;x++) {
        double xR = x/((double)xLen);

        double X = ((x2-x1)*xR+x1);
        double Y = ((y2-y1)*xR+y1);

        // Final estimation
        lookup(x,y)[0] = X;
        lookup(x,y)[1] = Y;
    }

}
```

All of dyl, dyr,yt_1, yt_2, xt_1, xt_2, ml, and mr are defined in code above and not changed by the for loop.

Am I expecting too much out of OpenMP for such small loop sizes?

EDIT: I've converted to a single loop, and still can't get a speedup.

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int p=0;p<xLen*yLen;p++) {
    int y = p/xLen;
    int x = p%xLen;

    double xR = x/((double)xLen);
    double yR = y/((double)yLen);

    double y1 = dyl*yR+yt_1;
    double y2 = dyr*yR+yt_2;

    double x1 = (y1-yt_1)/ml+xt_1;
    double x2 = (y2-yt_2)/mr+xt_2;

    double X = ((x2-x1)*xR+x1);
    double Y = ((y2-y1)*xR+y1);

    lookup[p] = X;
    lookup[p+xLen*yLen] = Y;            

}
```

Comment: Small loops will not give you any gains.  BTW, how many cores do you have?  I'm currently doing hw using OpenMP. Tow nested `for` loops with size 2160 are actually 5 magnitude slower then sequential `for` loop.

Comment: I thought that might be a problem so I converted it to a sequential for loop (I've added an edit above), but still can't seem to get a speedup.
I think the computer I'm working on now has 2 processors (it's kind of old).

Comment: `omp` needs some "warmup".  You could try to do you main `for` loop multiple times and measure speedup each time.  I think after the second or third time you could get a speedup.

Comment: You should define all your variables outside the for loop, then reuse the same variables rather than creating an instance of each variable for each for loop. I do not, either think that will have any effect with variables dependency. You might also want to try loop unrolling. If the xLen is 640 and yLen is 480, you could unroll it 2 or 5 times. On #pragma omp parallel for, you can include all of the private variables; private(p, y, x). shared variables; shared(xLen, yLen, lookup) etc.

Comment: You should also be aware that even if you make your function fully parallel, the machine that you are using should be in a position to handle multithreads. If you are running it on your home machine, I suggest you enable OMP variable environment among other environment setups, if you have not done so.

Comment: I was under the impression that Ubuntu and g++ were all set to handle OMP. How do I go about enabling the environment variables? Do you have a useful link for this?